# jquery-ui datepicker not appearing on dynamic input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, jquery-ui-datepicker

I inherited a bunch of code of varying quality and I'm fixing a bunch of things that has been wrong. One thing that it does is that is has a table of form inputs, one of which uses jquery-ui Datepicker. There is also a button that creates a new row at the bottom of the table. The new row's Datepicker never shows up.

I've seen this problem listed a few times here on SO but none of those solutions worked. I'm putting up what I have now. My jfiddle is at:

http://jsfiddle.net/squarepegsys/G8WEC/2/

The meat of my code is here:

```
tr.find(".datepicker").on("focusin",function() {
    console.log("got focus");
    $(this).datepicker();

});
```

In the on("focusin"...) line, I see "got focus" on the console but never see the datepicker show up.

Comment: When you clone the element you're also cloning the ID and IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: @j08691 But that doesn't solve problem right?

Comment: @j809 - Nope, but my answer below will ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create the datepicker instance, jQuery assigns it an ID, and when you clone it, you're duplicating it. Instead, create the datepicker instance dynamically via:

```
$(document).on('focus', ".datepicker", function () {
    $(this).datepicker( "destroy" ).datepicker();
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/G8WEC/6/)**

This will work for dynamically created elements and jQuery will manage the IDs properly.

Comment: That may be the fastest SO answer ever. I used a variation of datepicker("destroy").datepicker() and it worked wonderfully. I'm counting this -- and thanks!

Comment: @j08691, I fixed your example, it does not work when you first click textbox and after "add row", please, take a look at [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sergey4/WVguL)